# Fill a null value by finding similar strings, pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, null

I want to create a neural network that finds video game sales, using this dataframe:https://www.kaggle.com/gregorut/videogamesales

Is there a way to fill the null values of the Year column by finding similar named games from the Name column and putting their corresponding year to the null values.

That is the head of the dataframe

```
                      Name           Platform       Year            Genre       Publisher 
 
     1                Wii Sports        Wii         2006.0          Sports      Nintendo   
     2         Super Mario Bros.        NES         1985.0          Platform    Nintendo   
     3            Mario Kart Wii        Wii         2008.0          Racing      Nintendo   
     4         Wii Sports Resort        Wii         2009.0          Sports      Nintendo   
     5  Pokemon Red/Pokemon Blue        GB          1996.0      Role-Playing    Nintendo

 
     NA_Sales    EU_Sales    JP_Sales    Other_Sales         Global_Sales  

        41.49       29.02       3.77            8.46                82.74  
        29.08        3.58       6.81            0.77                40.24  
        15.85       12.88       3.79            3.31                35.82  
        15.75       11.01       3.28            2.96                33.00  
        11.27        8.89       10.22           1.00                31.37
```

Comment: Why do games with similar names translate to good placeholder year for games with null year values?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is use 'K-Nearest Neighbour' algorithm over your dataframe column name 'Year' and 'Name'. It will fill null values in 'Year' column.

Comment: How can i use K-Nearest Neighbors with strings?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Word2Vec` for creating vectors for word embedding similarity. Then, you can make a multi-class prediction for  `Year` column using those word embedding vector.